# -bash: javah: command not found on windows7

Tags: java, android

I am new to Android environment.I use this link(http://stevethai.wordpress.com/2010/08/04/android-helloworld-with-native-code-tutorial/) to run the NDK Project using NDK and cygwin Terminal.I follow all the steps given in the link.However during compiling in Cygwin Terminal it shows Error Like(-bash: javah: command not found).I specify all the path correctly.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Do you have `JRE` and `JDK` in your OS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you have `export PATH=$PATH:/cygdrive/c/Program\ Files/Java/jdk1.7.0/bin` set up it should work. Try restarting cygwin to reload env variables. Also, are you sure you are using the jdk and not the jre?

Comment: Thanks For your Response.In Path I didn't specify (\bin) i correct it and then i run the cygwin terminal command like ($ javah LibC.java).then it shows Error Like: error: cannot access LibC.java class file for LibC.java not found javadoc: error - Class LibC.java not found. Error: No classes were specified on the command line. Please Help . Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Hey no worries. So javah requires the class file, you are giving it the java source. The class file is what the source will compile into. So i imagine you need to compile LibC.java before you try to use it. Should be something like "javac LibC.java" which will make a class file called LibC. Then do "javah LibC.class" or whatever the output of the compilation was.

Answer (score 0):

may be you using DOS command in cygwin,enter DOS prompt,and set:

PATH c:\program files\java\jdk1.7.0_25\bin;%path%

then execute javah